# sqlite Query optimisation

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

The query

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Path LIKE 'geo-Africa-Egypt-%'
```

can be optimized as:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Path >= 'geo-Africa-Egypt-' AND Path < 'geo-Africa-Egypt-zzz'
```

But how can be this done:

```
select * from foodDb where Food LIKE '%apples%";
```

how this can be optimized?

Answer (score 1):

One option is redundant data. If you're querying a lot for some fixed set of strings occuring in the middle of some column, add another column that contains the information whether a particular string can be found in the other column.

Another option, for arbitrary but still tokenizable strings is to create a dictionary table where you have the tokens (e.g. `apples`) and foreign key references to the actual table where the token occurs.

In general, sqlite is by design not very good at full text searches.

Answer (score 0):

It would surprise me if it was faster, but you could try GLOB instead of LIKE and compare;

```
SELECT * FROM foodDb WHERE Food GLOB '*apples*';
```

Comment: Not any faster. Still results in a full table scan. Use sqlite's EXPLAIN to see the query plan i.e. the vdbe program to be run for a query.